# Identify this connector

Tags: connector, identification

I got this connector in a CIS sensor board

the connector is 18 pin , dimensions (around 5mm X 18 mm )

Here's some images for it the male & female [image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you measure the wire pitch?  Measure between the centers of the outer conductors, then divide by 18 (for 18-conductor FFC).

Comment: @markranges: Shouldn't that be 17, because there are 17 spaces between 18 pins? My guess would be 0.5mm pitch.

Comment: @markrages the  width is 8.5 mm ~ 9mm

Comment: Do you need to replace a damaged PCB connector, or the cable?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet PCB connector

Comment: @Rocketmagnet yes, should be 17.  So 0.5mm pitch.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet: probably 18, not 17, since there's some margin outside the first and last conductor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cable is a "flat flex cable" (FFC).  The connector is one of several hundred different types made for FFCs.  Without a LOT more information it would be almost impossible to narrow it down further.

For starters, we don't know the manufacturer.  Look carefully at the connector and there might be some identifying marks.  Next would be to know what the conductor pitch of the cable is.  Common values are 1.0, 0.8, 0.65, and 0.5 mm.  Those two pieces of info, along with what you've already given us, might narrow it down to at least a product series.

Comment: the  width is 8.5 mm ~ 9mm

Comment: AWM 20624 VW-1  is written on the cable,

Comment: @xsari3x I can read what's on the cable.  The size of the connector doesn't help.  You need to know the manufacturer of the connector.  There could be a logo or at least 3 or 4 letters embossed on the connector itself.  Without that then it is highly unlikely to find what the connector is.  It would be like searching for a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact part number, but this will get you close:

1. Go to Digi-Key.  http://digikey.com
2. Enter "FFC connector" in the search box.
3. Click on "FFC, FPC (Flat Flexible) - Connectors - Board Mount"
4. Select Number of Positions as 18
5. Select Pitch as 0.5mm
6. Select "Flip Lock" (that's how your opens, right?)
7. Click "Apply filters" and look at the pictures in the results.  You might make more measurements, e.g. height above PCB, to narrow the results some more.

One of the parts that you'll find with this procedure is Hirose FH19SC-18S-0.5SH(05):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the socket you have is one like this

Pitch FPC / FFC Connector (Flip-Lock Type) : http://jinlong.en.alibaba.com/product/50907754-50158186/0_5_Pitch_FPC_FFC_Connector_Flip_Lock_Type_.html

this is a datasheet for it:
http://www.hirose.co.jp/cataloge_hp/e58605370.pdf

and the connector is a FFC cable this is a datasheet for the 18-pin connector: http://www.parlex.com/tech_library/PS-1635RevB1.pdf